# Photos missing crop, automatically improve, etc

Tags: icons, photos

In Photos, when I first open the app, and select a picture I have all the editing options, but if I go back to the library view and select ANY photo after that the only tool shown at the bottom is the Slideshow icon. See photo: [image: only the slideshow icon remains]

Is there a way to restore the Photos app to it's original state? I've considered apt purge, but I'm a little nervous about uninstalling a native application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/elementary/photos/issues/153) with Photos which has recently been fixed. This should be resolved the next time Photos gets a new release and receives an update.

Comment: I can't believe the bug is still in effect in June 2018, almost a year later. I get they want to align new major features with elemantary OS Juno, but significant bugs...?